# HTML/PHP/MYSQL - How to populate a drop down with 2 different fields from MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having a rough time trying to figure out a way to create a drop down that is populated by 2 fields, first name and last name. However, when I try to do this only the last name shows... Any ideas/suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
</head> 
<body>
<form action="webfinal2.php"method="post">

<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
define('DB_USER', 'test');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'greatness');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

if(mysqli_errno($con))
{
    echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo "Connected to mySQL</br>";
}

echo "<select name= 'FirstName'>";
echo '<option value="">'.'--- Please Select Person ---'.'</option>';
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT first_name, last_name FROM demo");
$query_display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM demo");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<option value='". $row['first_name']."'>".$row['last_name']
 .'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<option>".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</option>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatinate `first name` with `last name`=>`".$row['last_name']."".$row['last_name']."`

```
<?
.
echo "<select name= 'FirstName'>";
echo '<option value="">'.'--- Please Select Person ---'.'</option>';
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT first_name, last_name FROM demo");
$query_display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM demo");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<option value='". $row['first_name']."'>".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

**Updated Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
</head> 
<body>
    <form action="webfinal2.php"method="post">
        <?php
        define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
        define('DB_USER', 'test');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'greatness');
        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

        $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

        if(mysqli_errno($con)) {
                echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        else {
                echo "Connected to mySQL</br>";
        }
        ?>
        <select name= 'FirstName'>
            <option value="">--- Please Select Person ---</option>
            <?php
            $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT first_name, last_name FROM demo");
            $query_display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM demo");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['first_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];?></option>
            <?php }?>
            </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```